# What is the motivation of the complex analytic spaces?

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I wonder about the motivations of the complex analytic spaces, nevertheless they are too complicated and difficult. Is it just a generalization of analytic subset of complex manifolds? Or, they have more importance themselves? I have heard that they appear in deformations of complex manifolds, but are there other examples where analytic spaces appeared naturally?